# grep to return the multiple matches of string variants per line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file which contains db sequence names

They have two forms as below

```
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, name = "My1_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY1_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "My2_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY2_SEQ")
```

I want to return MY1_SEQ and MY2_SEQ

If I use grep for _SEQ then I get the whole line

Ive tried to use awk

```
grep SEQ * | awk '{print $7}'
```

but this does not cope with the fact that each line could be slightly different.

I want to return the whole word (delimited by spaces) that matches _SEQ

How can I do this?

Comment: thaks for the responses. I will take a look. ONe thing that is too simplistic in my example is that the start of the sequence name might not always start  with M. It could start with any letter. I'll try out the below. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Po '(?<=sequenceName = ")[^"]*' filename
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to adjust your grep pattern a bit and use `-o` to return *only* the matched part:

```
$ echo '@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, name = "My1_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY1_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "My2_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY2_SEQ")' \
| egrep -o 'M.._SEQ(UENCE)?'
My1_SEQUENCE
MY1_SEQ
My2_SEQUENCE
MY2_SEQ
```

or of you just want the second one:

```
$ echo '@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, name = "My1_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY1_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "My2_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY2_SEQ")' \
| egrep -o 'M.._SEQ'
MY1_SEQ
MY2_SEQ
```

or, more generally, if you want `xxx_SEQ`:

```
$ echo '@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, name = "My1_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY1_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "My2_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY2_SEQ")' \
| egrep -o '[^ "]+_SEQ\b'
MY1_SEQ
MY2_SEQ
```

Comment: Thanks @veryhungrymike. THe second more general solution is almost what Im after. Im trying it with grep but it is returning nothing. I am trying  grep -o '[^ "]+_SEQ\b' *.java as it is reading my java files. Ive also tried ls *.java | egrep -o '[^ "]+_SEQ\b' but still no result

Answer (score 0):

If you use ack (http://beyondgrep.com) you can do this:

```
ack 'MY\d_SEQ.+' -w -o filename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **always** want the last field then `awk` gives you a variable called `NF` which can be used to retrieve the last value.

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[")]/,"",$NF);print $NF}' file
MY1_SEQ
MY2_SEQ
```

Using `gsub` we remove the quotes and parens.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  '{match($0, /MY.*_SEQ/,arr); print arr[0]}' input.txt
```

Input:

```
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, name = "My1_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY1_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "My2_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "MY2_SEQ")
```

Output:

```
MY1_SEQ
MY2_SEQ
```